# upload_to_play_store stays forever on "Preparing aab at path..."

Tags: android, flutter, fastlane

My setup:

fastlane 2.211.0

i used flutter to generate .aab file

```
desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play"
lane :deploy do
  upload_to_play_store(
           track: "internal",
           aab: "/Users/mac/abeer/fastlane-mobile/test2/Mobile/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab",
           skip_upload_apk: true )
end
```

but this message appears forever
Preparing aab at path '/Users/mac/abeer/fastlane-mobile/test2/Mobile/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab' for upload...

Comment: did you figure this out?